# Why am I able to assign a value to a read only property?

Tags: javascript, xpath

Apologies if this is a simple question. On this webpage:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html

I am using the following javascript to assign a value to an `input` element:

```js
var node = document.evaluate("//tr[contains(td/text(), 'Angelica Ramos')]/td[2]/input", 
  document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
node.singleNodeValue.value = "abc";
```

Result:

The input box value updates.

On reading about [XPathResult.singleNodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/singleNodeValue) it states:

> The read-only singleNodeValue property of the XPathResult interface
>   returns a Node value or null in case no node was matched of a result
>   with XPathResult.resultType being ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE or
>   FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE.

So, how is it that I am able to assign to the underlying object via this property?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't throw an error if you assign to readonly properties, but the value isn't actually changed. Try `var o = {}; Object.defineProperty(o, test, {readonly: true, value: 42}); o.test = 21; console.log(o.test);`

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. But then why does the value visibly change on the page?

Comment: Ah, from the description it seems that `node.singleNodeValue` is read only, but not `node.singleNodeValue.value`. Read only means that you cannot assign a new value to the property, but it doesn't imply that you cannot change *mutable* values.

Comment: @FelixKling   Ah... that makes sense. That sounds like the basis of an answer if you would like to post as such? And does this mean that whilst it changes visually - the value for that element is actually still 42?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer attributable to @Felix Kling

JavaScript doesn't throw an error if you assign to readonly properties, but the value isn't actually changed. Try

```
var o = {}; Object.defineProperty(o, test, {readonly: true, value: 42}); o.test = 21; console.log(o.test);
```

`node.singleNodeValue` is read only, but not `node.singleNodeValue.value`. `Read` only means that you cannot assign a new value to the property, but it doesn't imply that you cannot change mutable values.